# DropDown SelectedIndex set to 0 if Selection Repeated

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm having this linq query which checks for all 6 dropdowns whether there is any repetition in selction.

To do that , currently I'm setting SelectedIndex to 0 for all dropdowns. Instead of that , i want those two dropdowns.SelectedIndex=0 which has same SelectedValue.

```
        var allIndexes = new List<int>
        {
                drpdwnlst_Seq1.SelectedIndex,
                drpdwnlst_Seq2.SelectedIndex,
                drpdwnlst_Seq3.SelectedIndex,
                drpdwnlst_Seq4.SelectedIndex,
                drpdwnlst_Seq5.SelectedIndex,
                drpdwnlst_Seq6.SelectedIndex
        };

        var noSelectedIndexIsTheSame = allIndexes.Where(x => x != 0)
                                     .GroupBy(x => x)
                                     .All(x => x.Count() == 1);

        if (!noSelectedIndexIsTheSame)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "AdminUserError", "alert('Selection Rrepeated.'); ", true);

            drpdwnlst_Seq1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            drpdwnlst_Seq2.SelectedIndex = 0;
            drpdwnlst_Seq3.SelectedIndex = 0;
            drpdwnlst_Seq4.SelectedIndex = 0;
            drpdwnlst_Seq5.SelectedIndex = 0;
            drpdwnlst_Seq6.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the List to the following definition, (so you can keep most of your logic)

```
List<KeyValuePair<DropDownList, int>> allIndexes = new List<KeyValuePair<DropDownList, int>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<DropDownList, int>(drpdwnlst_Seq1, drpdwnlst_Seq1.SelectedIndex),
    new KeyValuePair<DropDownList, int>(drpdwnlst_Seq2, drpdwnlst_Seq2.SelectedIndex),
    new KeyValuePair<DropDownList, int>(drpdwnlst_Seq3, drpdwnlst_Seq3.SelectedIndex),
    new KeyValuePair<DropDownList, int>(drpdwnlst_Seq4, drpdwnlst_Seq4.SelectedIndex),
    new KeyValuePair<DropDownList, int>(drpdwnlst_Seq5, drpdwnlst_Seq5.SelectedIndex),
    new KeyValuePair<DropDownList, int>(drpdwnlst_Seq6, drpdwnlst_Seq6.SelectedIndex)
};

var groups = allIndexes.Where(x => x.Value != 0).GroupBy(x => x.Value);
boolean noSelectedIndexIsTheSame = groups.All(g => g.Count() == 1);

if (!noSelectedIndexIsTheSame)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "AdminUserError", "alert('Selection Rrepeated.'); ", true);

    foreach (var g in groups) 
    {
        if (g.Count() == 1) 
        {
            continue;
        }
        foreach (var kvp in g)
        {
            kvp.Key.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

this way, you have the reference of your combobox + the current selected index, you group by the KeyValuePair.Value, and you have a separate bool checking if no indexes are the same. If they are, it will loop the groups, and in case more than 1 was found per group, reset those

Comment: that's the correct logic. I applied but i get this error of 'ComboBox could not be found' . I referenced it with AjaxControlToolKit and after that i'm getting this. 'KeyValuePair(AjaxControlToolKit.ComboBox,int) has invalid arguments'

Comment: Yeah, i do not know which ui control you are using, what are you using from asp.net control, use that class as the base class for your KeyValuePair @DevenRavaliya

Comment: Done.  How can I convert <DropDownList,int> to int ? @ allIndexes.Where(x=>x!=0)